# How can I include literal curly braces in a Logback pattern encoder?

Tags: java, configuration, logback, literals

The syntax for patterns accepted by [`PatternLayoutEncoder`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/encoder/PatternLayoutEncoder.html) is partially specified in [the "layouts documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html), where it says

> In PatternLayout, parenthesis can be used to group conversion patterns. It follows that the '(' and ')' carry special meaning and need to be escaped if intended to be used as literals.
>
> ...
>
> % character has special meaning ... in order to include it as a literal, it needs to be escaped with a backslash, e.g. "%d %p \% %m%n".

However, it says nothing about the characters `{` and `}`. I wish to write a pattern which will output a literal open brace character. To this end I have tried, in my `logback.xml`:

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>{</pattern>
</encoder>
```

This causes Logback to fail with a `NullPointerException` when parsing the configuration file.

Then, by analogy with the escape character for the literal characters `%`, `(`, and `)`, I have tried:

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>\{</pattern>
</encoder>
```

This causes Logback to fail in the same way.

Presumably the `NullPointerException` is a bug in Logback. How do I work around it and output a literal brace character?

EDIT: here's the full stacktrace.

```
17:44:38,953 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.qos.logback.core.subst.Parser.T(Parser.java:77)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.subst.Parser.E(Parser.java:52)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.subst.Parser.C(Parser.java:122)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.subst.Parser.T(Parser.java:83)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.subst.Parser.E(Parser.java:52)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.subst.Parser.parse(Parser.java:48)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.subst.NodeToStringTransformer.tokenizeAndParseString(NodeToStringTransformer.java:55)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.subst.NodeToStringTransformer.substituteVariable(NodeToStringTransformer.java:46)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.substVars(OptionHelper.java:117)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.InterpretationContext.subst(InterpretationContext.java:159)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedBasicPropertyIA.body(NestedBasicPropertyIA.java:87)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBodyAction(Interpreter.java:295)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.characters(Interpreter.java:175)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:57)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1740)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the HTML unicode character for '{'

```
&#123;
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that -- same thing happens. The error is happening after XML deserialization. I'll add the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting single/double quotes before '{'. For me it solved one problem but opened another problem. I was trying to generate a JSON using PatternLayout. I could successfully generate JSON enclosed within quotes. However JSON parser started freaking out. In case you too are trying generate JSON and can not live with additional quotes, you may give JsonLayout a try. Solution is mentioned at https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output

Configuration I tried

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>'{"timestamp":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'}", "level":"%p", "classname":"%c", "logmsg":"%m'}</pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

It generated below log

```
'{"timestamp":"2018-08-21T15:18:49.998Z", "level":"INFO", "classname":"com.myproject.log4jTest.logbackTest", "logmsg":"Hello world."}'
```